# PHP OOP: curl_close or unset, which one is correct?

Tags: php, oop, curl, unset

I'm new to OOP programming, I'm involved recently in the web scraping topic so here my problem: based on this [old question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3566155/php-destructors) when I come across the costruct/destruct methods using cURL with PHP, I don't know if I should use curl_close or unset. Which one is correct? In other words, does unset($ch) close the curl session when used in the destruct method?
My class is structured as follows:

```
class UsingCurl {
    // Properties: cUrl handle, various constants, etc.
    private $ch;
    ...
    public function __construct( ) {
    // setup cookie file with fopen
    // init cURL
    curl_init( $this->ch );
    // setup main cURL options with curl_setopt
    }

    // various methods

    public function __destruct( ) {
    // store session data to db or file
    // closing cURL session with curl_close or unset($this->ch)?
    }
```

Comment: cURL init should be written like this: `$this->ch = curl_init();`

Answer (score 2):

You should be using `curl_close` cause this will close curl session and free all resources. It will also delete curl handle:

```
Closes a cURL session and frees all resources. The cURL handle, ch, is also deleted.
```

And this is what it does to handle:

```
$ch = curl_init();
var_dump($ch); // resource(3, curl)
curl_close($ch);
var_dump($ch); // resource(3, Unknown)
```

There is no harm if you do both curl_close and unset like this:

```
public function __destruct( ) {
    curl_close($this->ch);
    unset($this->ch);
}
```