# Default routing behavior if methods fail to find a valid route?

Tags: php, oop, model-view-controller, routes

I'm updating a PHP framework I've written. It used to just use a default behavior for routing. For example consider a case where the request goes to `domain.com/package/controller/method`...

```
$url = ["package", "controller", "method"];
//Check if package exists...
//Check if controller exists in package...
//Check if method exists in controller...
```

I asked a question about using the `__deconstruct` method for this function [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37802463/using-destruct-to-implement-default-routing/37802705#37802705) that may have to been to specific. I'm opening this broader question because `__deconstruct` is not the solution to my problem.

This is all well and good, and works perfectly. However, I wanted to add some additional functionality to my router. That functionality being the ability to define custom routes, and pass an anonymous function which does whatever you want.

However, supposing that the request does not match any of the user-defined routes, I want to use the default functionality I have now to check if there are additional possible routes. That way I can update old projects with the new framework and not have them break, and additionally...I just like this default behavior because most of the time routes are not that complicated and defining routes feels like a violation of DRY to me.

The problem is that I don't want to pass the user-defined routes as an array to the object constructor. Rather, I want the user to call them as methods on the base application object similar to how Laravel or Express handles this.

The problem is that I want the default route checking to happen AFTER the user's defined routes have been checked not before. This quasi-code might help you understand what I mean...

```
class App
{
  __construct
  {
    //Check Default Routing
  }
  private function get()
  {
    //Get Request
  }
  private function post()
  {
    //Post Request
  }
  private function put()
  {
    //Put Request
  }
  private function delete()
  {
    //Delete Request
  }
}

app::get();
```

In the above case, the default routing would take place before the user-defined routes are called.

I have explored the following possibilities...

1. Doing the default routing before and loading the user-defined controller if it exists.

The problem with this method is that if the default router finds a match and executes a controller method, it will echo out it's contents, and THEN echo out the contents of the user-defined controller. This is obviously a problem.

2. Passing user-defined routes as arrays to the `__construct` function.

This works, but is extremely sloppy and degrades the object's usability. That is without mentioning that this leads to a more procedural coding style, and I would like the routes to be handled as methods on the application object.

3. Having an explicit method which does the default routing and telling the user to call this method if they want to use it.

This also works, but it's less than satisfactory. I want all of this to happen behind the scenes without the developer having to worry about it. It should be a default behavior of the class. Furthermore, if the developer calls this method before he calls a routing method, we'll display two controller method results again.

Is there a way to keep using methods for the routing to maintain the OOP style of my framework and also call the default routing method after all of the user-defined routing methods have been called?

Comment: With default behavior, I assume that `[package][controller]` is called but not the `method`. So when the controller is called, but not explicitly with a method, the controllers default method should be called. And your focus here is on _how_ to implement default behavior for any controller right? What's the behavior when a method of a controller requested doesn't exist? Does it trigger default or some other method?

Comment: Nope. That part is already done. Let's say a developer defined some routes with the methods on the application object. Let's say that none of the custom routes matched the URI. Then the application object should try my default routing to check for matches. I would just use the construct method, but I want the object to only call the default router when none of the user defined routes match. That means the application object should call this function after it stops having its methods called.